# Haskell type signature with multiple class constraints

Tags: haskell, types, static-typing, type-signature

How can I have multiple class constraints, so if `A` is an `Eq` and `B` is a `Num`, I could say either

```
f :: Eq a => a -> b`
```

or

```
f :: Num b => a -> b
```

So, how can I have `Eq a =>` and `Num b =>` at the same time?

- `f :: Eq a => Num b => a -> b`,
- `f :: Eq a -> Num b => a -> b`, and
- `f :: Eq a, Num b => a -> b`

didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

They're usually called *class constraints*, as `Eq` and `Num` are called type-classes.

How about this?

```
f :: (Eq a, Num b) => a -> b
```

The parentheses are significant.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Do these parentheses with a comma cause a higher-level tuple of some kind, or is this another meaning of parentheses?

Comment: @Andrew actually they do (now) although you probably should not be worrying yourself about such things just yet.  Normall Haskell types have *kind* (type of type) `*`, so the tuple type has kind `* -> * -> *`.  In recent versions of GHC there is a new kind `Constraint` such that `Eq :: * -> Constraint`, and tuples have been promoted to this new kind.