# Haskell Multiple Contexts - currying?

Tags: haskell, types

When writing contexts on a type signature, ordinarily I would do something like

```
f :: (Enum a, Ord a) => a -> a
```

But through sheer dumb luck I found that this compiles and seems to work identically, at least on GHC 7.8:

```
f :: Enum a => Ord a => a -> a
```

What are the theoretical or practical differences between the two?  Is the second one less orthodox?  The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004) seems to make no mention of the second form, and I've never seen it used anywhere.  [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093847/haskell-type-signature-with-multiple-class-constraints).

Comment: SPJ presented a lecture once in which he explained what constraints compile to. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6COvD8oynmI - In short, they're function arguments in their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two versions are the same. Constraints and `forall`-s are floated out to the top of the scope when they are not already there. For example, the following definitions are valid:

```
foo :: a -> a -> Num a => a
foo = (+)

bar :: a -> forall b. b -> a
bar = const
```

But `:t foo` prints `Num a => a -> a -> a` and `:t bar` prints `a -> b -> a` (which is equivalent to `forall a b. a -> b -> a`).

GHC doesn't support polymorphic return types, that's why the constraints and quantifiers are floated out. I guess it could have been also a valid design choice for GHC to throw errors.

Comment: Although the first should be a parser error if one follows the 2010 grammar rigorously. Then, on the other hand, [GHC's parser](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Parser.y) is full of things I can't comprehend.

Comment: FTR, here is the relevant part of the parser: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/851ed7211fb18fea938be84c99b6389f6762b30d/compiler/parser/Parser.y#L1082