# RankNTypes and the dot operator

Tags: haskell

When I use RankNTypes, it seems that (.) operator doesn't work well. Where is this limitation documented?

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

f :: Int -> (forall r. r -> r)
f = undefined

g :: (forall r. r -> r) -> Int
g = undefined

h :: Int -> Int
-- h v = g (f v) -- It works well
h = g . f -- I can't write it in this way
```

I get following errors.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:11:9:
    Couldn't match type ‘r0 -> r0’ with ‘forall r. r -> r’
    Expected type: Int -> forall r. r -> r
      Actual type: Int -> r0 -> r0
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘f’
    In the expression: g . f
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: This has little to do with `.` in particular, it's just that _fully automatic type inference is not possible with general higher-rank types_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, how is inference related? Bidirectional type checking + unification should cover this case. Agda is [happy](http://lpaste.net/137326) at least.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, `f` doesn't have type `Int -> (forall r. r -> r)`, because GHC [floats out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069938/haskell-multiple-contexts-currying) every `forall` and class constraint to the top of the scope. So `f`'s type is really `forall r. Int -> r -> r`.

For example, the following typechecks:

```
f :: Int -> (forall r. r -> r)
f = undefined

f' :: forall r. Int -> r -> r
f' = f
```

This makes the `g . f` composition ill-typed (we can see that the error message points explicitly at the discrepancy between `r -> r` and `forall r. r -> r`).

It would be probably better behavior for GHC to throw errors upon finding `forall`-s in wrong places, instead of silently floating them out.

There are several reasons why polymorphic return types (which are outlawed by floating-out `forall`-s) aren't allowed in GHC. For details you can refer to [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/putting.pdf) (section 4.6 specifically). In short, they only make sense if there is solid support for impredicative instantiation, which GHC lacks. In the absence of impredicative types, floating-out allows more terms to typecheck and rarely causes inconvenience in real world code.