# Is it possible to use church encodings without breaking equational reasoning?

Tags: list, haskell, church-encoding, equational-reasoning

Mind this program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Prelude hiding (sum)

type List h = forall t . (h -> t -> t) -> t -> t

sum_ :: (Num a) => List a -> a
sum_ = \ list -> list (+) 0

toList :: [a] -> List a
toList = \ list cons nil -> foldr cons nil list

sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
-- sum = sum_ . toList        -- does not work
sum = \ a -> sum_ (toList a)  -- works

main = print (sum [1,2,3])
```

Both definitions of sum are identical up to equational reasoning. Yet, compiling the second definition of works, but the first one doesn't, with this error:

```
tmpdel.hs:17:14:
    Couldn't match type ‘(a -> t0 -> t0) -> t0 -> t0’
                  with ‘forall t. (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t’
    Expected type: [a] -> List a
      Actual type: [a] -> (a -> t0 -> t0) -> t0 -> t0
    Relevant bindings include sum :: [a] -> a (bound at tmpdel.hs:17:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘toList’
    In the expression: sum_ . toList
```

It seems that `RankNTypes` breaks equational reasoning. Is there any way to have church-encoded lists in Haskell without breaking it??

Comment: Yes, but it will involve hacking on a compiler... rank-2 type inference is decidable, but nobody's implemented it. Rank-3 type inference is undecidable (hence the existence of both `Rank2Types` and `RankNTypes`, even though they currently do the same thing).

Comment: It's very hard for me to understand what you mean by "equational reasoning" here. You're working with an isomorphism that is quite clearly not the usual equality.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not sure I know what equational reasoning means, then. I assumed it meant you are free to always inline definitions / beta reduce functions.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what you were doing. Sorry.

Comment: It is okay, I don't know too.

Comment: @DanielWagner okay then, I guess. :(

Comment: @Viclib You could of course also use the rank-1 version of the Church encoding, `type List r a = (a -> r -> r) -> r -> r`, and be careful that you never provide something monomorphic as the first argument of `List`. It is sad that you can't get the compiler to help you check that, but is also a *lot* less work.

Comment: Well, that is what I was using before, but then how you write `head`? I tried and it couldn't typecheck for good.

Comment: @Viclib Remember that it's okay to specialize to the left of arrows. So I would guess `head :: List (Maybe a) a -> Maybe a; head f = f Just Nothing` or `unsafeHead :: List a a -> a; unsafeHead f = f id undefined`.

Comment: Note that `[a] -> List a` is a type that [doesn't actually exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627124/rankntypes-and-the-dot-operator/31629197#31629197) in GHC, which makes `sum_ . toList` just plain ill-typed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the impression that ghc percolates all for-alls as left as possible:

```
forall a t. [a] -> (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t)
```

and

```
forall a. [a] -> forall t . (h -> t -> t) -> t -> t
```

can be used interchangeably as witnessed by:

```
toList' :: forall a t. [a] -> (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t
toList' = toList

toList :: [a] -> List a
toList = toList'
```

Which could explain why `sum`'s type cannot be checked. You can avoid this sort of issues by packaging your polymorphic definition in a `newtype` wrapper to avoid such [hoisting](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.4-latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-extensions.html#hoist) (that paragraph does not appear in newer versions of the doc hence my using the conditional earlier).

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Prelude hiding (sum)

newtype List h = List { runList :: forall t . (h -> t -> t) -> t -> t }

sum_ :: (Num a) => List a -> a
sum_ xs = runList xs (+) 0

toList :: [a] -> List a
toList xs = List $ \ c n -> foldr c n xs

sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum = sum_ . toList

main = print (sum [1,2,3])
```

Comment: This is indeed how you should define `List`.  GHC has a rather second class treatment of rank-n types, and using them without a newtype wrapper is going to hurt.

Comment: Great answer, I hope yours gets accepted over mine. =D

Comment: It should also be noted that `newtypes` add no overhead.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a somewhat frightening trick you could try. Everywhere you would have a rank-2 type variable, use an empty type instead; and everywhere you would pick an instantiation of the type variable, use `unsafeCoerce`. Using an empty type ensures (so much as it's possible) that you don't do anything that can observe what should be an unobservable value. Hence:

```
import Data.Void
import Unsafe.Coerce

type List a = (a -> Void -> Void) -> Void -> Void

toList :: [a] -> List a
toList xs = \cons nil -> foldr cons nil xs

sum_ :: Num a => List a -> a
sum_ xs = unsafeCoerce xs (+) 0

main :: IO ()
main = print (sum_ . toList $ [1,2,3])
```

You might like to write a slightly safer version of `unsafeCoerce`, like:

```
instantiate :: List a -> (a -> r -> r) -> r -> r
instantiate = unsafeCoerce
```

Then `sum_ xs = instantiate xs (+) 0` works just fine as an alternative definition, and you don't run the risk of turning your `List a` into something TRULY arbitrary.

Comment: That again... I think I'll just lose the fear and start adopting unsafeCoerce on my vocabulary. You're creating a monster, sir.

Comment: @dfeuer What do you propose instead?

Comment: Dunno. Not that. Sometimes the cure is worse than the disease. I don't really see the problem that needs to be solved here.

Comment: This isn't really constructive but I love dfeuer's reaction, no less than I expected heh

Comment: (I still don't understand why Haskellers love the type system so much more than they love equational reasoning... I just tend to think nothing in the world comes before it, not even types.)

Comment: @Viclib I think you should keep your fear. It might be a good idea to try to prove that `unsafeCoerce` is actually safe -- perhaps the free theorem for `List a` (or maybe `Void`?) will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: That's horrible. There are no guarantees about unsafeCoerce in general. Any use outside implementation specific modules should be punished in the harshest possible way.

Comment: @augustss I think "the compiler doesn't have inference for Rank2Types yet" is one of the perfectly valid excuses. After all, it means the term *is* correct. Using unsafeCoerce and providing a separated proof looks as acceptable as it gets. Why not?

Comment: @augustss I look forward to your proposal for an improved alternative.

Comment: After type checking, my ideal compiler would optimize `f :: T -> Void` as roughly `\_ -> undefined`, and `g :: T -> ()` as `\_ -> ()` when a termination checker succeeds (similarly for other single-value types, e.g. `a:~:b`). Since GHC is not (yet) that smart, I guess `unsafeCoerce` should work, for now. It looks quite dangerous, though.

Comment: How does this enable equational reasoning?

Comment: @PyRulez The complaint in the question is that `sum_ . toList` and `\a -> sum_ (toList a)` do not have the same type (one does not even type-check using the code in the question). With my setup, these two terms do indeed both typecheck and produce the same type.

Answer (score 6):

Generally equational reasoning only holds in the "underlying System F" that Haskell represents. In this case, as others have noted, you're getting tripped up because Haskell moves `forall`s leftward *and* automatically applies the proper types at various points. You can fix it by providing cues as to where type application should occur via `newtype` wrappers. As you've seen you can also manipulate when type application occurs by eta expansion since the Hindley-Milner typing rules are different for `let` and for lambda: `forall`s are introduced via the "generalization" rule, by default, at `let`s (and other, equivalent named bindings) alone.