# Is there any way to make this Church-encoded program compile?

Tags: haskell, types

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

type CList a = (forall t . (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t)

ccons :: forall a . a -> CList a -> CList a
ccons h t = (\ c n -> c h (t c n))

cnil :: forall h . CList h
cnil = (\ c n -> n)

cToList :: forall a . CList a -> [a]
cToList list = list (:) []

cFromList :: forall a . [a] -> CList a
cFromList = foldr ccons cnil

main = print (cToList (cFromList [1,2,3]))
```

I understand the reason it doesn't compile has to do with the usage of `forall` on `ccons`. Commenting the `ccons` type will make it compile, but with an awkward type for `ccons`. What is the right way to fix it?

```
test.hs:15:23:
    Couldn't match type ‘(a -> t -> t) -> t -> t’
                   with ‘forall t1. (a -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1’
    Expected type: a
                   -> ((a -> t -> t) -> t -> t) -> (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t
      Actual type: a -> CList a -> (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t
    Relevant bindings include
      cFromList :: [a] -> CList a (bound at test.hs:15:5)
    In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘ccons’
    In the expression: foldr ccons cnil
```

Comment: Actually, the issue isn't with `forall`. It's actually saying that the `t` in your `ccons` function is different from the `t` in your `cFromList` function. Hence the `t` and `t1` business.

Comment: Yes, but can I fix it somehow?

Comment: I feel so sure that you've asked something really similar to this before and got told to use `newtype` instead of `type` (which should do fine as a solution here, too), but I can't find the question now...

Comment: Impredicativity bites.

Comment: @DanielWagner sorry, I probably did, but I ask so much and do so much work in parallel that it is almost impossible even for myself to keep track of my own legacy :( I wish I could just stop, sit and learn instead of living like that. Oh well

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing for when I asked about the **Scott** encoding? I was told I need `newtype` instead of `type` for it to work [and it does indeed](http://lpaste.net/151650)... that's all I remember, though. Couldn't find anything that looks like the answer to this question googling for myself. Maybe I'm just not making the connection. Sorry :(

Comment: Basically, if you introduce a new rank-n-type, wrap it in `newtype`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `ccons` at all? `cFromList` is just a flipped `foldr`

```
cFromList ::  [a] -> CList a
cFromList xs op seed = foldr op seed xs
```

Comment: Oh. Or that, lol. Thanks. (Is there any problem in not using `newtype`, though? I don't quite understand well the source of this problem - I don't know if it will break something later on or if there will always be an obvious solution like this one.)

Comment: Newtyping the Church encoding will have a number of advantages. It will make type messages more intelligible and will permit, e.g. Functor and Monad instances and so on.

Comment: I think usually when I have done things like this and 'really' just wanted the rank-2 type, I would also keep the newtyped version around to use when I couldn't get the compiler to grasp my meaning.

Comment: @Viclib, all sorts of things with go wonky without the `newtype`. All your `forall`s will get shoved as far to the left as possible. A `newtype` will block `forall` migration so you can get results as polymorphic as you need. There will surely be other reasons too.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @Daniel Wagner, merely using `newtype` instead of `type` solves the issue:

```
newtype CList a = CList { runCList :: (forall t . (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t) }

ccons :: forall h . h -> CList h -> CList h
ccons h t = CList (\ c n -> c h (runCList t c n))

cnil :: forall h . CList h
cnil = CList (\ c n -> n)

cToList :: forall a . CList a -> [a]
cToList list = runCList list (:) []

cFromList :: forall a . [a] -> CList a
cFromList list = (foldr ccons cnil list)

main = print (cToList (cFromList [1,2,3]))
```

Also apparently I was told this before but I really can not remember nor find the question. Sorry guys :(

Comment: [That's the one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931432/is-it-possible-to-use-church-encodings-without-breaking-equational-reasoning/31942453#31942453)

Comment: @gallais oh I even read that one before... so I guess I was too stupid to notice they were related.